# How to print text between specific words(as Inputs arguments) in Shell scripting

Tags: shell, sed

I want to print complete text between specific words. Here is my requirement.

"123.log" contain below text.

```
EBSPRODSTART
web logic server
Oracle database administration
Linux operating system
EBSPRODEND
```

### Output should be:-

```
web logic server
Oracle database administration
Linux operating system
```

### Brief:-

Above word "EBSPROD" is database name. This value will be an input argument.
e.g.

```
$ DBNAME=EBSPROD
$ echo $DBNAME
EBSPROD
$
```

Am trying like below but it is not printing any value.

```
$ cat 123.log |sed -n '/^$DBNAMESTART$/,/^$DBANEMEND$/p'
```

If am passing DBNAME value directly am getting the output as below.

```
$ cat 123.log |sed -n '/^EBSPRODSTART$/,/^EBSPRODEND$/p'
web logic server
Oracle database administration
Linux operating system
$
```

Note:- DBNAME will not be same value every time when i execute the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. `'...'` doesn't interpolate any variables. You need `"..."` for that.
2. `$DBNAMESTART` looks for a variable called `DBNAMESTART`. You need `${DBNAME}START`.
3. `DBANEMEND` is not the same as `DBNAMEEND`.

Thus:

```
sed -n "/^${DBNAME}START\$/,/^${DBNAME}END\$/p"
```

Comment: Can you help me how to print the result line by line.

Comment: Present Output:-
$ DBNAME=ebspdv1
$ value=`cat /tmp/Patch_info/123.log|sed -n "/^${DBNAME}START\$/,/^${DBNAME}END\$/p"|grep -v $DBNAME|cut -d: -f2-3|sed 's/\"//g'`
$ echo $value
web logic server Oracle database administration Linux operating system
$

Comment: I want output like below.. 
$ echo $value
web logic server
Oracle database administration
Linux operating system
$

Output should print line by line

Comment: @Kumar Comments don't show multi-line code, but it looks like you're simply missing `"` around your variable: `echo "$value"`